# Storing XML in a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <Animals>
        <Pet name ="Ruby">
            <Owner name = "John Smith"/>
            <Type name = "Dog"/>
            <Breed name = "Labrador"/>
            <Sex name = "Female"/>
            <Desexed name = "Yes"/>
            <Age name = "7 years"/>
        </Pet>
        <Pet name ="Charlie">
            <Owner name = "John Q"/>
            <Type name = "Dog"/>
            <Breed name = "Pug"/>
            <Sex name = "Female"/>
            <Desexed name = "No"/>
            <Age name = "2 Years"/>
        </Pet>
    </Animals>
</root>
```

and I wish to store the name of the element and the value of its 'name' attribute for every 'Pet' and its descendants in a nested dictionary. I don't know if a dictionary would be the best way to store this information or not, but if I was to store it in a dictionary I would store it in a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` where the key is the pet name (e.g. Ruby, Charlie) and the key of the nested dictionary is each attribute name (Owner, Type, Breed, Sex, Desexed, Age) and the value is the value of the name attribute. Can anyone help me with this? I find LINQ really confusing. At the moment I have this stored in a `XDocument`.

Comment: Did you have a question? It's not entirely clear what you're asking here. Guessing on my part: the information for each "Pet" looks like a single data-container object to me. Why not just declare a single class with Owner, Type, Breed, etc. as properties where you store those pieces of information? You can use instances of that class as values in a dictionary where the pet name is the key.

Comment: `I wish to store it` how? for what?  this is incredibly vague

Comment: Is the Pet name unique? if not Dic is not you best option

Comment: You can read the XML and store in memory (if this is what u mean) it by using XmlDocument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
var dictionary =
    xd
        .Descendants("Pet")
        .ToDictionary(
            x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
            x => x.Elements()
                .ToDictionary(
                    y => y.Name,
                    y => y.Attribute("name").Value));
```

I get this result:

[image: nested dictionry]

Comment: Thanks very much. I changed one minor thing which was 'y => y.Name' to 'y => y.Name.ToString()' so that the nested dictionary is <string, string> and not <XName, string>. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a class 'Pet' as the module for the data and read each element into the Pet class. Then, I would just save the Pets in an array. A dictionary is not a good option as the Pet names could be not unique.